# MySQLI not connecting? query not running

Tags: php, sql, azure, azure-sql-database

Im not going to lie, im really really lost here. This is my first attempt at connecting a database from php. Ive chosen to use microsoft azure to host my page as well as my database. Im also not exactly sure where to find the DB hostname/username/pass and such. Ive found some code working through a microsoft tutorial which worked for connecting but now trying to insert a row I feel it may have been a crutch.

Can someone tell me where im going wrong or at least point me in the right direction?

```
<?php

$connectstr_dbhost = '';
$connectstr_dbname = '';
$connectstr_dbusername = '';
$connectstr_dbpassword = '';

foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
if (strpos($key, "MYSQLCONNSTR_acmedb") !== 0) {
continue;
}

$connectstr_dbhost = preg_replace("/^.*Data Source=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
$connectstr_dbname = preg_replace("/^.*Database=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
$connectstr_dbusername = preg_replace("/^.*User Id=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
$connectstr_dbpassword = preg_replace("/^.*Password=(.+?)$/", "\\1", $value);
}

$link = mysqli_connect($connectstr_dbhost, $connectstr_dbusername, $connectstr_dbpassword,$connectstr_dbname);
mysqli_error($link);

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'users' (id, fname, lname, age)
VALUES (1, 'James', 'Casimir', 20)";

if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error:james " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
}
mysqli_close($link);



?>
```

Comment: `foreach ($_SERVER` - where's that coming from?

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT INTO 'users'` that's failing.

Comment: Whats wrong with the $sql bit? Im honestly not completely sure what that code does, thats part of the bit copy/pasted from the tutorial. also can you explain whats happening with the preg_replace? Its just kind of magic code to get the database hostname and stuff

Comment: incorrect identifier qualifiers

Comment: What exactly does that mean? Im honestly really new to this.

Comment: either delete the quotes or use ticks `\`` instead of quotes `'`

Comment: I dont think thats the problem, I have tried it every which way, including without qutoes. Im thinking it has more to do with the connection.

Comment: if you think the quotes belong, then I'm wrong then or mysql is wrong https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Comment: you also never answered my 1st comment.

Comment: no no no, im saying that changing the quotes doesnt fix the problem. I tried changing that stuff up before asking as part of general troubleshooting.

Comment: Ohh, that was the bit in my first comment that I said was copy pasted. Sorry that wasnt very clear.

Comment: I have flagged this question as Off Topic -> Cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

A warm thank you to Aaron Chen for providing an actual input sample.  This helped me to understand the data.

If you don't know the exact `MYSQLCONNSTR_...` key name, then you can use `array_filter()` to extract it from the `$_SERVER` array instead of a foreach loop.

Of course, if you do know the exact `$_SERVER` key that you want to access, then you can use `$_SERVER[whateverkey]` directly in my `preg_match_all()` call.

You can use `preg_match_all()` and `list()` to generate the appropriate variables with less code than your `preg_replace()x4`.  My little regex pattern is demonstrated/explained [Here](https://regex101.com/r/Tn2GSQ/1).

```
// if you don't know the exact key name:    
$value=current(array_filter($_SERVER,function($k){return strpos($k,"MYSQLCONNSTR_")!==false;},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));

// if you do know the exact key name:
$value=$_SERVER["MYSQLCONNSTR_acmedb"];

// echo "TEST: $value<br>";
// my regex pattern returns all values in order between equals and semicolons
if(preg_match_all("/(?<==)[^;]+/",$value,$captured)){
    //var_export($captured[0]);
    list($db,$host,$user,$pass)=$captured[0];
}else{
    echo "Error extracting DB info with preg_match";
}
```

In the first condition, you can declare and check `$link`.
In `$sql`, it is safest to use backticks (`) around tablenames and columnnames (this is not always necessary).
The second condition, will declare (run) and check `$mysqli_query()`'s result.

```
if($link=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db)){
    $sql="INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`fname`,`lname`,`age`) VALUES (1, 'James', 'Casimir', 20)";
    if(mysqli_query($link,$sql)){
        if(($aff_rows=mysqli_affected_rows($link))>0){
            echo "New record created successfully ($aff_rows)";
        }else{
            echo "Query Logic Error: $sql";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Syntax Error: ",mysqli_error($link);
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
}else{
    echo "Connection Error: ",mysqli_connect_error());  // not mysqli_error()
}
```

***Note***: Do not echo any errors when your site goes live; you don't want the public to have access to this information.  Simply comment the lines that print to screen by prepending them with `//`.

Comment: Getting somewhere! It tripped the connection error condition. Honestly I believe this has something to do with the configuration for getting the user/hostname/password

Comment: @NotYourDuck I have used Aaron Chen's very useful information to refine your connection data extraction process.  Please implement my code and let me know if there is anything left to address.  Please confirm that `$value` has some kind of string in it.

Answer (score 1):

Base on your description, I suppose you are using Azure App Service MySQL in-app. Since you set up **MySQL In App** to **On**, Azure will run a local MySQL instance with your app, and set the connection string to environment variable `MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb`.

[image].

You can also check that environment variable via `phpinfo()` function.

[image]

So please consider the following code snippet to get connection string:

```
foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value)
{
    if (strpos($key, "MYSQLCONNSTR_") !== 0)
    {
        continue;
    }

    $connectstr_dbhost = preg_replace("/^.*Data Source=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbname = preg_replace("/^.*Database=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbusername = preg_replace("/^.*User Id=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbpassword = preg_replace("/^.*Password=(.+?)$/", "\\1", $value);

}
```

For more details, please refer to [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/08/18/announcing-mysql-in-app-preview-for-web-apps/).

Comment: I must say that I found this information useful and I wish Not Your Duck would have posted it in the question itself. However it is essentially a comment that asks: "Do you know if the $_SERVER key that you are accessing actually exists? If not, here is a workaround to access it."  You only actually altered one line, so the full foreach loop block was unnecessary to post.